# Connect to PgSQL, DROP existent DB, recreate it using CREATE and run some queries alone and from files using Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql

I need some advice creating a script for help me with repetitive task I do all the time on a development environment. I've a PostgreSQL server and since I'm developing a web application I need to drop, create and fill some tables all the time and this is a tedious process. So I need to build some kind of bash script for help me out on this. Basically this is the repetitive tasks I do all the time, from a pgAdmin GUI:

```
#!/bin/sh
psql -u postgres -w  // this line should connect to PostgreSQL asking for a password since I not found other way to pass the password on that line

DROP DATABASE sis_db; // drop the DB

CREATE DATABASE sis_db WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'UTF8' TABLESPACE = pg_default LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1; // create the DB

// Create some schemas on the DB ( I don't know if I should select the DB first)
CREATE SCHEMA nomencladores AUTHORIZATION postgres;
CREATE SCHEMA negocio AUTHORIZATION postgres;
CREATE SCHEMA usuarios_externos AUTHORIZATION postgres;
```

And finally I should load around 10 `.sql` files but don't know if `-filename` allow more than one file at time. I need some advice on this bash script since I don't know how to get it, can any give me some help?

**Update: First script approach**

Ok, by doing a deep research I come with this solution that works but miss some things that I need too. I made this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# kill all connections to the postgres server
echo "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity where pg_stat_activity.datname='sis_db';" | psql -U postgres -w

# drop the DB
echo "DROP DATABASE sis_db;" | psql -U postgres -w

# create the DB
echo "CREATE DATABASE sis_db WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'UTF8' TABLESPACE = pg_default LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;" | psql -U postgres -w

# create schemas
echo "CREATE SCHEMA nomencladores AUTHORIZATION postgres;" | psql -U postgres -d sis_db -w
echo "CREATE SCHEMA negocio AUTHORIZATION postgres;" | psql -U postgres -d sis_db -w
echo "CREATE SCHEMA usuarios_externos AUTHORIZATION postgres;" | psql -U postgres -d sis_db -w
```

It will use a `/root/.pgpass` file that I've created and configure. The script right now is working as I want but what I don't know is how to add several files at the same time, meaning for example, after schemas creation execute the content of `sql1.sql`, `sql2.sql` and so on, any help or advice?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a skeleton that may be used directly in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
psql -U postgres << END_OF_SCRIPT

DROP DATABASE sis_db; -- drop the DB

CREATE DATABASE sis_db WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'UTF8' TABLESPACE = pg_default LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

\c sis_db

-- Create some schemas on the DB

CREATE SCHEMA nomencladores AUTHORIZATION postgres;
CREATE SCHEMA negocio AUTHORIZATION postgres;
CREATE SCHEMA usuarios_externos AUTHORIZATION postgres;

END_OF_SCRIPT
```

A few comments:

- `-u` wouldn't work, it's `-U`, options are case sensitive.
- `CREATE DATABASE` does not automatically connect to the new database, `\c sis_db` does and is the only way for objects created later in the script to belong to that database.
- end-of-line comments start with `--` in SQL, not `//`
- The `--file` option cannot be used several times on the command line, only the last one will be honored. However `\i fileN.sql` from inside `psql` may be used to include a series of files.
- be cautious about errors. By default, a script will continue after an error, possibly having undesirable effects such as creating objects in the wrong database. This may be avoided with `-vON_ERROR_STOP=1` on psql's command line, or `\set ON_ERROR_STOP on` from inside the script.
- Check psql's [manpage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html), it explains all this and much more.

Comment: can you take a look to my latest adition? I figure out the script but miss some parts and I don't know how to add them, can you help me to complete the script?

Comment: Since your update already runs a new psql for every SQL command, I can't see how aligning a list of `psql -f script1.sql`... `psql -f scriptN.sql` would be a problem.